# how to run an imported react native project in vs code

Tags: react-native, import, project

I have downloaded this file and saved in my computer which has some react native code. I want to run this in vs code, but it is giving an error. I run the following command

`C:\Users\Downloads\flat-code> npx expo start`

it gives the following error

`ConfigError: Cannot determine which native SDK version your project uses because the module` expo `is not installed. Please install it with "yarn add expo" and try again.`

I tried the `yarn add expo` but again there is error `yarn : The term 'yarn' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.`

How can I successfully import a project and run it?